# Characteristic Polynomial of a matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Does a matrix and and its transpose have the same characteristic polynomial? I know that they have the same eigenvalues but different eigenvectors. Does having the same eigenvalues mean they share the same characteristic polynomial?

Comment: See the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798918/show-that-arbitrary-a-and-at-have-same-eigenvalue-algebraic-and-geometric?rq=1).

Comment: A matrix over a field is always similar to its transpose.

Comment: Yes.  (Presumably you're talking about square matrices)

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123926)

Answer (score 1):

For all $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$, 
$$\det(A-XI_n)=\det(^t(A-XI_n))=\det(^tA - XI_n)$$